# export variable to linux using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, export

I want to export variables to linux using shell script. My shell scrip is as following:

```
export dbHost=server01
export dbName=someName
```

when I print these variable after running script I get the following output

```
"eclare -x dbHost=" server01
declare -x dbName=" someName "
```

So it correctly exports the dbName but not dbHost. If I keep only the first line

```
export dbHost=server01
```

in the script then it prints dbHost correctly. 
What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: @anubhava  by typing this command ". ./fileName.sh" (without quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have DOS line ending in your file that you can test with:

```
cat -t file.sh
```

That will show something like this:

```
export dbHost=server01^M
export dbName=someName^M
```

To fix this issue run `dos2unix` on your `file.sh`.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

> when I print these variable after running script

The variables you `export` will only be visible inside the shell your script runs in and in subshells. If you want to see the effects after your script terminates, you have to `source` your script.

An explanation can be found in answers to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) on superuser.